# EGOPhotoViewer: Start at specific photo

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I am using EGOPhotoViewer to load up a bunch of images from the web.  They are shown in thumbnails first, so when a user clicks on one of the thumbs, I want to show that image in the EGOPhotoViewer first.  So, if I clicked the 5th image, it would load the image viewer starting at 5 of 20 or whatever.

Is there a way to do this?

```
ZSPhoto *photo;

for (Asset *a in items) {
    photo = [[ZSPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:a.imgURL] name:a.caption];
    [photos addObject:photo];
    [photo release];
}

// Photosource
ZSPhotoSource *photoSource = [[ZSPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:[NSArray arrayWithArray:photos]];
EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:photoSource];

// Set starting photo index here?

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoController];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
[photoController release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method `moveToPhotoAtIndex:animated:` that you should be able to use.

Comment: I see that and have tried it, but the app crashes when trying to use it.

Comment: Can u plz tell me how u solved ur crash, bcoz i am also getting a crash while using movetoPhotoAtIndex:animated method

Comment: @Nic Hubbard :  hi nic, can u plz tell me how u solved the crash. it seems that my app crashes only in release(distribution) mode. it runs fine in debug mode. does someone has an idea y this could be happening????

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem, What I was doing was trying to moveToPhotoAtIndex: before pushing it to the navigationController.  You need to do it after.

here is how i got it to work for my application...

// gets indexPath from tableView

```
-(void)showSelectedPhoto:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Already had photoControllerView declared in header, init with your photo source
    photoControllerView = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];

    // pushed the photoControllerView to the navigation controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];

    // THEN you moveToPhotoAtIndex and it should work correctly!
    [photoController moveToPhotoAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:NO];
}
```

Hope this helps clarify things!

Answer (score 0):

i am using same process to load the images in image viewer. and app is working fine for me..you can get the code from here

[selected image wouldnt load in ego image viewer in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270749/selected-image-wouldnt-load-in-ego-image-)

hope you will get help.