# selected image wouldn't load in ego image viewer in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, ios7

I am using EGOPhotoViewer to load up a bunch of images from the s3. They are shown in thumbnails first in table view, so when a user clicks 5th row of image, it loaded the image into image viewer starting at 5 of 20 . and this is working smoothly in ios 6.

but when I installed ios 7 and run my app.I got an error. it fails to load the clicked image.
when user click 5th row of image,image viewer load the very 1st image starting at 1 of 20.

i am using this much of code.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath

 {  ......


  [self showSelectedPhoto:indexPath];

 ......
}
  //load the selected image
  -(void)showSelectedPhoto:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 [UserInfo sharedInfo].Path=indexPath;
 NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
 NSString *passingImageName=[[self.tableDataSource          objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"fileName"];
 NSMutableArray *photoArray=[self getFilteredArray];
 NSMutableArray *urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 //  [self.tableView reloadData];
  for (NSString *string in photoArray) {

     NSLog(@"String Values:%@",string);
     NSURL *imageUrl=[self getEnlargedImageImageUrl:[self._prefix stringByAppendingString:string]];
    NSLog(@"Passing url is:%@",imageUrl);
     photo = [[EGOQuickPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:imageUrl name:string];

    [urlsArray addObject:photo];
}


self.source=[[EGOQuickPhotoSource alloc]initWithPhotos:urlsArray];

photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];
NSUInteger index = [photoArray indexOfObject:passingImageName];
 NSLog(@"index = %lu",(unsigned long)index);


[photoController moveToPhotoAtIndex:index animated:NO];
  }
```

so it is ios 7 ui bug or whatever?

Answer (score 4):

```
 I got the solution of this,And it working fine For my app in IOS 7. 

              In EGOphotoviewer 


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

NSInteger _index = [self centerPhotoIndex];
if (_index >= [self.photoSource numberOfPhotos] || _index < 0) {
    return;
}

//Change here for IOS7...add "&&_index>0" after _rotating 
if (_pageIndex != _index && !_rotating && _index > 0) {

    [self setBarsHidden:NO animated:YES];
    _pageIndex = _index;
    [self setViewState];

    if (![scrollView isTracking]) {
        [self layoutScrollViewSubviews];
    }

}
```

}

Comment: k it is working fine, but i am facing small problem. In ipad 6.1 simulator at one image i am not able to scroll, its fine in  all other simulators

Comment: Works for me too. Tons of Thanks for finding solution. Have a happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In EGOphotoviewcontroller in viewwillappear method

```
  if ([self.navigationController isToolbarHidden] && (!_popover || ([self.photoSource numberOfPhotos] > 1))) {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

After calling this method in ios7 _pageindex value getting zero,i don't know the actual reason for this, but i will give one idea. 
 just assign _pageindex value  after this statement,like indexpath.row or may be tag value what youwant to assign,

Then the things are going good...
njoy...